# How to make sure there are an equal amount of elements in two Python lists?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, numpy

I have two lists each with a length of about 1.6 million items. Each item is either blank or has an embedded list within it of 1 or more strings. Unfortunately, there's missing data in one of the lists such that the two don't correspond. I want to write the contents of these lists to a flat dataframe, but can't if the arrays are different lengths.

I've already tried a for-loop that embeds NAs in one of the lists when it detects that an item has a different length in one list from another, but that approach takes a really long time given that it has to loop through 1.6 million items.

Is there a faster, more elegant way of doing this rather than via the for-loop approach. Letting the whole thing run takes about 6 hours as it stands.

Edit: Here is an example of what I mean:

```
list_A = [[''],[''],[''],['a'],['a','b','c'],[''],['d']]
list_B = [[''],[''],[''],['a'],[''],[''],['']]
```

What I'd like is to place NAs in the empty lists in list_B such that list_B would look like:

```
list_A = [[''],[''],[''],['a'],['a','b','c'],[''],['d']]
list_B = [[''],[''],[''],['a'],['NA','NA','NA'],[''],['NA']]
```

Comment: numpy.array.size should be fast enough

Comment: Is this a numpy related question? If so, tag as such.

Comment: @idjaw I don't know, but I added the tag in case it helps.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean.  Do the two lists have the same number of elements?  When you say "each item .. has an embedded list within it," do you mean "each item ... is a list"?  If not, please give an example.  Does the "NA" go in the list or in the list item?  Please give a short example, along with the desired result.

Comment: Since these are lists of lists, with varying length sublists, this is not a good fit with `numpy`.  Like it or not you'll have to iterate through all the items in the lists.  You can't shove the iteration down into compiled code.

Comment: @saulspatz: Edited with example.

Comment: @StanO: In the example, the two sublists are either identical, or one is an empty string.  Is this always the case?  Also, when the two items are different, the empty string is always in list B.  Again, is this always the case?

Comment: As far as I understand it, the program needs to go through both lists, check if each element of the list matches the corresponding element of the other list in length, if not, insert a "matching" list with the placeholder values into the shorter list. A problem with this sort of solution, however, is what if the missing value is identical in length to the value that comes after it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your example, the corresponding items are either identical, or the one in `list_B` should be replaced by a list of `NA`'s of the same length as the item in `list_A`.  This generator expression should be fast enough:

```
(a if a==b else len(a)*['NA'] for a,b in zip(list_A,list_B))
```

Comment: That's exactly it and solves my example problem perfectly! 

I just noticed that I made my example incorrectly. What list_B should have had was numbers instead of letters, (i.e. something different.) So what I was looking for was just a slight modification to your code, which I'll put here in case it can help anyone else:

(b if len(a)==len(b) else len(a)*['NA'] for a,b in zip(list_A,list_B))